# Laravel 9 Inertia with vitejs-plugin-legacy for browser compatibility

Tags: vuejs3, vite, laravel-9, inertiajs

I have setup an application project with Laravel 9 Inertia (with vue 3) and vitejs. I need to provide support for old browsers like Safari v11.

To ensure the compatibility of old browser versions, I use what is recommended by Vite :

https://vitejs.dev/plugins/#vitejs-plugin-legacy

However, after running an "npm run dev" or "npm run build" the js won't load and gives me a blank page with errors in return.

[Return of Safari 11 with Laravel 9 Inertia :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eBDs.png)

By testing with a fresh install of Laravel 9 and the associated scaffodling (Inertia, vue3), I find the same problem.

Vite.config.js :

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import path from 'path'
// import babel from 'vite-plugin-babel';
import legacy from '@vitejs/plugin-legacy'

export default defineConfig({
    test: {
        globals: true,
        environment: 'jsdom',
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
          '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './resources/js'),
          ziggy: path.resolve('vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist'),
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
             input: ['resources/scss/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            // ssr: 'resources/js/ssr.js',
                refresh: true,
            }),
        vue({
                template: {
                    transformAssetUrls: {
                        base: null,
                        includeAbsolute: false,
                    },
                },
        }),
        legacy({
            targets: ['safari >= 11'],
            cspHashes : [
                'MS6/3FCg4WjP9gwgaBGwLpRCY6fZBgwmhVCdrPrNf3E=',
                'tQjf8gvb2ROOMapIxFvFAYBeUJ0v1HCbOcSmDNXGtDo=',
                'p7PoC97FO+Lu90RNjGWxhbm13yALSR4xzV8vaDhaQBo=',
                '+5XkZFazzJo8n0iOP4ti/cLCMUudTf//Mzkb7xNPXIc='
            ],
            additionalLegacyPolyfills: ['core-js/proposals/global-this'],
        }),
     ],
});
```

Package.json :

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "test:unit": "vitest",
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build && vite build --ssr",
        "watch": "vite build --watch"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.22.5",
        "@babel/core": "^7.22.5",
        "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.5",
        "@inertiajs/vue3": "^1.0.0",
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
        "@vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet": "^0.9.0",
        "@vue/server-renderer": "^3.2.31",
        "@vue/test-utils": "^2.2.7",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "browserslist-to-esbuild": "^1.2.0",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.2",
        "leaflet": "^1.9.3",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.4.18",
        "sass": "^1.62.1",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.2.1",
        "terser": "^5.18.1",
        "vite": "^4.0.0",
        "vite-plugin-babel": "^1.1.3",
        "vitest": "^0.32.2",
        "vue": "^3.2.41"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@grafikart/drop-files-element": "^1.0.9",
        "@inertiajs/vue3": "^1.0.6",
        "@vitejs/plugin-legacy": "^4.0.5",
        "@vuelidate/core": "^2.0.2",
        "@vuelidate/validators": "^2.0.2",
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
        "bootstrap-vue-3": "^0.3.12",
        "bootstrap-vue-next": "^0.8.8",
        "browserslist": "^4.21.9",
        "sass-loader": "^13.2.2",
        "swiper": "^9.2.4",
        "vue-image-zoomer": "^2.2.3",
        "vue3-recaptcha2": "^1.7.0"
    }
}
```